# Resources not being built into jar in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, build

I had this problem before, but don't remember how I solved it. I have some FXML files in my resources folder, and it is marked as a resource folder. The resources are copied to the build directory (not under classes, but resources). The problem is that the resources are not copied to the jar when built.

I tried adding the resources folder to the jar manually in the artifact config, but that didn't work.

Comment: what version of intelliJ are you using?

Comment: @MarquisBlount The most recent one, 14.1.5. I am also running Linux if that helps :)